# Select single selection from cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

i have a table view in which there are two sections and cells under it. User can select only one cell from the each section,i have tried some code for selection, when i select any cell from section 0 it remove the tick sign from section 1 and when i select any cell from section 1 it removes tick sign from section 0 and i also want when the table view loads its first cell of each section should be pre selected. i have code for single selection in my table view, but for pre selection i don't have an idea so how can i preselect a cell.This is my code,

```
extension FiltersVC: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionTitles[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuItems[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = filterTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filterCell", for: indexPath) as! FiltersTableViewCell

    cell.tilteLbl.text = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9130856497, green: 0.9221261017, blue: 0.9221261017, alpha: 1)

    let headerText = UILabel()
    headerText.textColor = UIColor.black
    headerText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    switch section{
    case 0:
        headerText.textAlignment = .center
        headerText.text = "LIST BY"
        headerText.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9190355449, green: 0.9281349067, blue: 0.9281349067, alpha: 1)
        headerText.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    case 1:
        headerText.textAlignment = .center
        headerText.text = "COUSINE"
        headerText.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
        headerText.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    default: break

    }

    return headerText

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let cell = filterTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

            let item = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(item, forKey: "listBy")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            filterBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            filterBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
    else {
        if let cell = filterTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

            let item = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(item, forKey: "Cuisine")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            filterBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            filterBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let cell = filterTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
    else{
        if let cell = filterTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable multiple selection. In `viewDidLoad()` put:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Then handle only allowing one selection in each section in the `didSelectRow()` delegate method by checking `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` which returns an array of index paths.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Get list of all selected index paths (includes one just selected, so may be up to 3)
    var selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!

    // Remove index path that was just selected
    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath)!)
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        // Get any selected index paths in section 0
        let selectionInSection0 = selectedIndexPaths.filter { $0.section == 0 }
        if !selectionInSection0.isEmpty {
            // Deselect the preciously selected row in section 0
            tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionInSection0.first!, animated: true)
        }

        // Other required code from user
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            let item = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(item, forKey: "listBy")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            filterBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            filterBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)
        }

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        // Get any selected index paths in section 1
        let selectionInSection1 = selectedIndexPaths.filter { $0.section == 1 }
        if !selectionInSection1.isEmpty {
            // Deselect the preciously selected row in section 1
            tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionInSection1.first!, animated: true)
        }

        // Other required code from user
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            let item = menuItems[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(item, forKey: "Cuisine")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            filterBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            filterBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529120326, green: 0.3879342079, blue: 0.09117665142, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: from this it selects multiple cell , but i want to select only single cell from each section and it should pre select first cell of each section. @Chris

Comment: The second part of the answer gives an idea of how to do that. I’m working on an example now.

Comment: i didn't get that please if u can share the code? @Chris

Comment: I’m only on my iPhone so can’t test this just yet. There may be a couple of warnings about needing to unwrap optionals when getting the index paths of the selected rows.

Comment: its showing error  Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. on this line of code  let selectedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows. @Chris

Comment: @raheem I'm fixing that error now. Your other code is fine, though you refer to the `tableView` as `filterTableView` - when in the `didSelectRow` delegate methods, it is referred to as just `tableView` (unless of course you are referring to a different `tableView`.

Comment: I have updated my answer and incorporated your other code as well.

Comment: bro the app crashes at same point. When i select an cell from section 1 it crash.@Chris

Comment: through ur code its selecting multiple cells but i want select only one cellfrom each section. @Chris

Comment: With my code I'm trying to get the array of all selected cells and if the user has selected in section 1, it deselects any other selected cell in section 1. I have updated my code again - give it a try @raheem

Comment: but i don't have this scenario. @Chris

Comment: @raheem Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: Hi! Do you know how to clear selected checkmarks in UserDefaults? For example, if user launches app for the 2,3 time, selected cells should be unchecked.

Comment: @Abrcd18 You could override the `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` method in app delegate and empty user defaults there. You can also set an observer for the app moving to the background.